# self-document a returned data-structure of a function that uses one-frame allocator

Tags: c++, c++14, allocator

How to self-document a function that use a custom allocator - to remind that its user **must not** cache the returned result.

I have a library and a user class, they use in-house polymorphic allocator.

- **Library** : uses one-frame-allocator to generate return result of `Library:fLib` .
  The returned result will be invalid at the end of time-step.
- **User**  : want to cache the return result of `Library:fLib`  to use in later frame.
  It is a bad design ; hence it needs some warning.

Here is the snippet.  ([full demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d79fe87982ae15d1)).

```
class Library{
    public: 
    OneFrameAllocator allo_;
    public: Report fLib(){   //<-- may need some semantic documentation
        Report report;
        report.setAllocator(&allo_);
        return report;
    }
};
Library lib;
class User{
    Report tmpCache;
    public: void fUser(){
        Report arr=lib.fLib();   //<-- still OK (should not warn)
        tmpCache=arr;            //<-- wrong usage, but hard to detect
    }

};
int main(){
    User user;
    user.fUser();
    lib.allo_.clearOneFrame();
    //HERE: user.tmpCache become dangling pointer internally (danger)
    return 0;
}
```

### Question

How to warn coder of `User` **not to cache** return result of `Library::fLib()` semantically
 (i.e. more than just comment `/**/`)?

I am considering to use smart pointer, but I don't think it can help because memory become invalidated from custom allocator, not from deleting a `unique_ptr`.

In real life, `Library` can also be a custom `Array` (that acts similar as `std::vector`).
In such case, the danger less obvious - "`User` try to copy `Array`" doesn't seem to be dangerous.

Sorry if the question is too newbie, I am very new to custom allocators.

**Edit:**
After looking into the rule of three. (thank paddy)
I believe the core of my problem can be [depicted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUFh1.png)  as :-

```
(pseudo code)
class Lib{
    OneFrameAllocator allo;
    public: std::unique_ptr<int> make_unique(){
        return allo.make_unique<int>(); 
        //^ memory will be invalidated when call "allo.clearOneFrame()"
    }
    public: void update(){
        allo.clearOneFrame();
    }
};
Library lib;
class User{
    std::unique_ptr<int> cache=nullptr;
    public: void fUser(){
        //do something about "cache"  <--- crash expected at 2nd frame
        std::unique_ptr<int> temp=lib.make_unique(); //<-- still OK
        cache=std::move(temp);            //<-- danger
    }
};
int main(){
    User user; 
    //--- 1st frame ----
    user.fUser();
    lib.update();
    //--- 2nd frame ----
    user.fUser();  //<--- crash expected
    lib.update();
}
```

I believe the problem is :
The class that has ownership (`User`) is not the class that controls memory allocation (`Library`).

It is not a good design, so I want to find a way to warn the coder of `User` that something is wrong by using C++ syntax/semantic-clue.

Comment: This is more an issue of not following the [Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4172722/1553090).  You get a dangling pointer because you allowed copy semantics that did not create a true copy.  Either delete the copy constructor and assignment operator (which will give you a compile error if you try to cache the value), or implement them properly (which will copy it properly, potentially via another custom allocator).

Comment: @paddy Should I create a custom copy function that has allocator as parameter?  I have to sacrifice convenience of default copy constructor and copy assignment. (?)

Comment: Maybe you should look at how the C++ standard library handles custom allocators.  It's not quite the same as how you're doing it.  Anyway, the moment you have non-trivial memory semantics, you need to have non-trivial constructor/destructor.  You may also need to correctly handle move semantics (C++11 and above).  The _convenience_ you speak of is actually laziness.  Your usage pattern is a bit strange, as you have exposed your allocator publicly and talk about invalidating memory owned by another object.  That breaks encapsulation.  Maybe this is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @paddy Thank for useful comments.   I found that standard library use allocator as [a template parameter](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) (I don't like), and polymorphism allocator is still an experimental feature (thus, it is so hard to find an example show extensive usage, best I found = https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38010544/polymorphic-allocator-when-and-why-should-i-use-it).   ...  To avoid XY problem (or to make it easier to point out whether it is),  I have edited question to depict the problem in a somehow different way.  I would be glad if you may take a look.