# What is the purpose and usage of `memory_resource`?

Tags: c++, c++17, allocator

The standard `C++17` include a new namespace `pmr` including a set of classes grouped under the name of `memory_resource`.

After a search on internet, I found very few vulgarized information about it, the direct consequence is this question:

**What are the main ideas behind `pmr` and especially `pmr::memory_resource`?**

---

Detailing a bit more the question, some of the question marks in my head are:

- What does it bring new, or what were the limitations it solve?
- What is the difference with `allocator`?
- Does polymorphic mean it is possible to select runtime the `allocator` provided to a container constructor? (e.g. for testing purpose)
- Does it helps for implementing memory pool, or other memory management schemes?

---

Context:

In the intend of creating a `memory pool` allocator, I found information about this namespace. Reading names like `pool_options` or `polymorphic_allocator` raised my attention.

---

Related questions:

[polymorphic_allocator: when and why should I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38010544/polymorphic-allocator-when-and-why-should-i-use-it)

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/memory_resource

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38010544/polymorphic-allocator-when-and-why-should-i-use-it

Comment: @Curious: Very interesting link, and if you agree, I will relate it as it explain a sub-set of the topic.

Comment: @AdrianMaire I don't think I follow, do you mean you want to include it in the question?  If so go for it 

Comment: @AdrianMaire: But all of your questions are answered there. `memory_resource` is what you derive from to achieve the polymorphic allocation functionality, as exposed through the allocator type `polymorphic_allocator`.

Comment: @NicolBolas: inclusion is mono-directional: Polymorphic_allocator is part of memory_resource, but memory_resource is not only polymorphic_allocator. I especially focus memory pools, so there is a full chapter about `pool_options`, `synchronized_pool_resource`, `unsynchronized_pool_resource` `monotonic_buffer_resource`, `memory_resource class`.. and only `polymorphic_allocator` is half answered. On the other hand, you closed because of **duplicated question** not **duplicated answer** (Remember that people do not know the answer and search by **question**)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A `polymorphic_allocator` is intended to let you have an allocator whose behavior is dynamically determined at runtime.

The only way to create a `polymorphic_allocator` is:

1. Default constructed, in which case it uses `std::pmr::get_default_resource()` return value, which is a `memory_resource*`.
2. Pass it a `memory_resource*`.
3. copy from another `polymorphic_allocator`.

So the point of customization for a `polymorphic_allocator` is creating a class that inherits from `memory_resource` and implementing its methods, *or* using one of the pre-declared `memory_resource`s that are defined in `std::pmr`: (`un`)`synchronized_pool_resource` and `monotonic_buffer_resource` as types, or `std::pmr::new_delete_resource()` / `std::pmr::null_memory_resource()`.

Suppose you want a your memory to be allocated using a strategy different than the 5 provided in `std::pmr`.  Then you make a class that inherits from `std::pmr::memory_resource`, and pass it to a container which uses a `polymorphic_allocator`.

Comment: What is the difference compared to `allocator`?

Comment: @matt first paragraph?

Comment: Could you give more information as to why a regular allocator can't determine its behavior at runtime? After all, it is a function that gets invoked in the same way.

Comment: @mattf An allocator is a type that satisfies specific requirements, not a function.  pmr is a type that satisfies the allocator requirements, so you are free to reproduce the implementation of pmr in your hand written allocator type.  Such a hand written pmr won't be`std::pmr`, but it will otherwise behave the same.

Comment: Allocators are a bit wierd.  If you have questions about them in general, I'd advise asking a question rather than making a comment.

Comment: `Such a hand written pmr won't be std::pmr, but it will otherwise behave the same.` Might be good to add that to the answer as I felt it didn't address that part of the question as it stands.

Comment: @markf I am answering what pmr is, not how allocators work.  I get that there are people not fluent in C++, but honestly I have to assume some competence.  "What is a template", "what is an allocator", "what is a class", "what is a type", "how do std containers use allocators" - I can write a book.  I am answering what pmr is, assuming you understand all of that (and more).  The other questions are best solved via the [ask question] button.  Someone can write a better answer for each of those problems.