# Custom allocator compatibilty

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, vector, allocator

Given the following function signature

```
void foo(std::vector<int> &bar);
```

and a custom allocator `CustomAlloc`, calling foo with a instance of `std::vector<int, CustomAlloc>` results in

```
could not convert ‘bar’ from ‘std::vector<int, CustomAlloc<int, [...] >}’ to ‘std::vector<int>’
```

I am no C++ template guru and please do correct me if I am wrong but my understanding is that `std::vector<int>` default to `std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >` (gcc 7.1.1.-3) and hence defines a completely unrellated type.

---

This beeing said I am trying to find some solutions to make `foo` callable using `std::vector<int, CustomAlloc>` and came with the following.

```
template<typename Allocator>
void foo(std::vector<int, Allocator> &bar);
```

I dislike how the allocator specification propagates templates, but I guess that is how the STL works.

So my question is, how would you solve this problem given that `foo` specically operates on `int`?

PS: Apologies for the bad title I just couldn't find a good one

Comment: It's not clear if you need `foo` to take different types of parameters, but if the requirement is to use `CustomAlloc` only, you can declare it `void foo(std::vector<int, CustomAlloc> &bar);` without any templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an entirely new namespace in the standard for solving this issue - `namespace pmr`.  See [polymorphic_allocator: when and why should I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38010544/polymorphic-allocator-when-and-why-should-i-use-it)

As to what you can do to avoid the propagation of this issue with templates without the `pmr` solution.  The answer is you can't, you need to either hard specify the allocator parameter, or you need to template the vector to accept any type of allocator.

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising and  proposes an elegant solution to this problem.