# Should every fancy pointer be an iterator?

Tags: c++, crtp, allocator, fancy-pointers

I'm working on a segment-based memory allocator for C++. In this allocator, when you deallocate a chunk of memory, you have to know which *segment* it came from. Therefore, I'm storing a pointer to the segment as a member of the fancy `pointer` returned from the allocator's `allocate` function.

Just to show the interface I'm talking about: here's the `fancy_memory_resource` that backs my allocator...

```
template<class Ptr>
class fancy_memory_resource {
public:
    Ptr allocate(size_t bytes, size_t align = alignof(max_align_t)) {
        return do_allocate(bytes, align);
    }
    void deallocate(Ptr p, size_t bytes, size_t align = alignof(max_align_t)) {
        return do_deallocate(p, bytes, align);
    }
    bool is_equal(const fancy_memory_resource& rhs) const noexcept {
        return do_is_equal(rhs);
    }
    virtual ~fancy_memory_resource() = default;
private:
    virtual Ptr do_allocate(size_t bytes, size_t align) = 0;
    virtual void do_deallocate(Ptr p, size_t bytes, size_t align) = 0;
    virtual bool do_is_equal(const fancy_memory_resource& rhs) const noexcept = 0;
};
```

(Notice that `std::pmr::memory_resource` can be implemented as a typedef for `fancy_memory_resource<void*>`. This is intentional on my part.)

Meanwhile, the `Ptr` in question is a fancy pointer type named `segmented_fancy_pointer<T>` (not pictured) that inherits from the CRTP type `fancy_ptr_base<T, segmented_fancy_pointer<T>>`...

```
template<class T, class CRTP>
struct fancy_ptr_base {
    constexpr T *ptr() const noexcept { return m_ptr; }
    constexpr explicit operator T*() const noexcept { return ptr(); }
    constexpr explicit operator bool() const noexcept { return ptr() != nullptr; }
    constexpr bool operator==(CRTP b) const { return ptr() == b.ptr(); }
    constexpr bool operator!=(CRTP b) const { return ptr() != b.ptr(); }
    constexpr bool operator==(decltype(nullptr)) const { return ptr() == nullptr; }
    constexpr bool operator!=(decltype(nullptr)) const { return ptr() != nullptr; }
    constexpr bool operator<(CRTP b) const { return ptr() < b.ptr(); }
    constexpr bool operator<=(CRTP b) const { return ptr() <= b.ptr(); }
    constexpr bool operator>(CRTP b) const { return ptr() > b.ptr(); }
    constexpr bool operator>=(CRTP b) const { return ptr() >= b.ptr(); }
    constexpr T& operator*() const noexcept { return *ptr(); }
    constexpr T* operator->() const noexcept { return ptr(); }
    constexpr CRTP& operator+=(ptrdiff_t i) { m_ptr += i; return as_crtp(); }
    constexpr CRTP& operator-=(ptrdiff_t i) { m_ptr -= i; return as_crtp(); }
    constexpr CRTP& operator++() { ++m_ptr; return as_crtp(); }
    constexpr CRTP& operator--() { --m_ptr; return as_crtp(); }
    constexpr CRTP operator++(int) { auto r(as_crtp()); ++*this; return r; }
    constexpr CRTP operator--(int) { auto r(as_crtp()); --*this; return r; }
    constexpr CRTP operator+(ptrdiff_t i) const { auto r(as_crtp()); r += i; return r; }
    constexpr CRTP operator-(ptrdiff_t i) const { auto r(as_crtp()); r -= i; return r; }
    constexpr ptrdiff_t operator-(CRTP b) const { return ptr() - b.ptr(); }

protected:
    T *m_ptr = nullptr;
private:
    constexpr CRTP& as_crtp() { return *static_cast<CRTP*>(this); }
    constexpr const CRTP& as_crtp() const { return *static_cast<const CRTP*>(this); }
};

template<class CRTP>
struct fancy_ptr_base<void, CRTP> {
    constexpr void *ptr() const noexcept { return m_ptr; }
    constexpr explicit operator void*() const noexcept { return ptr(); }
    constexpr explicit operator bool() const noexcept { return ptr() != nullptr; }
    constexpr bool operator==(CRTP b) const { return ptr() == b.ptr(); }
    constexpr bool operator!=(CRTP b) const { return ptr() != b.ptr(); }
    constexpr bool operator==(decltype(nullptr)) const { return ptr() == nullptr; }
    constexpr bool operator!=(decltype(nullptr)) const { return ptr() != nullptr; }
    constexpr bool operator<(CRTP b) const { return ptr() < b.ptr(); }
    constexpr bool operator<=(CRTP b) const { return ptr() <= b.ptr(); }
    constexpr bool operator>(CRTP b) const { return ptr() > b.ptr(); }
    constexpr bool operator>=(CRTP b) const { return ptr() >= b.ptr(); }
protected:
    void *m_ptr = nullptr;
};
```

Now for the real question. When I go to use my `segmented_allocator<T>` (not pictured) with libc++'s `std::vector`, it all works fine. When I try to use it with libstdc++'s `std::vector`, it fails:

```
In file included from /opt/wandbox/gcc-head/include/c++/8.0.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:67:0,
                 from /opt/wandbox/gcc-head/include/c++/8.0.0/vector:60,
                 from prog.cc:1984:
/opt/wandbox/gcc-head/include/c++/8.0.0/bits/stl_iterator.h: In instantiation of 'class __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<scratch::segmented_fancy_pointer<int>, std::vector<int, scratch::pmr::propagating_polymorphic_allocator<int, scratch::segmented_fancy_pointer<int> > > >':
/opt/wandbox/gcc-head/include/c++/8.0.0/bits/vector.tcc:105:25:   required from 'std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::reference std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::emplace_back(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {int}; _Tp = int; _Alloc = scratch::pmr::propagating_polymorphic_allocator<int, scratch::segmented_fancy_pointer<int> >; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::reference = int&]'
/opt/wandbox/gcc-head/include/c++/8.0.0/bits/stl_vector.h:954:21:   required from 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type&&) [with _Tp = int; _Alloc = scratch::pmr::propagating_polymorphic_allocator<int, scratch::segmented_fancy_pointer<int> >; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = int]'
prog.cc:1990:18:   required from here
/opt/wandbox/gcc-head/include/c++/8.0.0/bits/stl_iterator.h:770:57: error: no type named 'iterator_category' in 'struct std::iterator_traits<scratch::segmented_fancy_pointer<int> >'
       typedef typename __traits_type::iterator_category iterator_category;
                                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Now, I *can* fix this by adding the "iterator traits" typedefs into `fancy_ptr_base<T, CRTP>`, like this:

```
    using pointer = CRTP;
    using reference = T&;
    using value_type = std::remove_cv_t<T>;
    using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;
    using difference_type = ptrdiff_t;
```

But should I have to? Is it *required* that every fancy pointer type be an iterator type as well? Or is libc++ doing the right thing and libstdc++'s `vector` just has a bug?

(I have already convinced myself that [most *iterators* are not fancy pointers](https://github.com/Quuxplusone/from-scratch/blob/master/include/scratch/bits/traits-classes/pointer-traits.md#what-is-a-pointer). This question is motivated by my sudden doubt that perhaps all *fancy pointers* are indeed iterators.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are required to implement all requirements of a [Random Access Iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator).  C++ Standard [allocator.requirements]/5:

> An allocator type `X` shall....  `X::pointer` and `X::const_pointer` shall also satisfy the requirements for a random access iterator.

So in particular, your fancy pointer type needs the five member types required of every [iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Iterator).

You also seem to be missing `fancy_memory_resource<Ptr>::value_type`, several needed non-member functions, and a number of `noexcept` keywords.  Please review the [requirements for allocator types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator) and their pointer types carefully.

Comment: Thanks. Re your last paragraph, nit: I didn't post the code for my `segmented_allocator<T>`, which is the thing with the `value_type`. My `fancy_memory_resource` is just a fancified version of `std::pmr::memory_resource`, and as such does not have any `value_type` (it deals in raw bytes, not `T`s). What non-member functions were you thinking of, besides `==` and `!=` and maybe `swap`?

Comment: Yeah, `==` and `!=` for the allocator type, plus supporting `nullptr == fancy_ptr`, `nullptr != fancy_ptr`, `number + fancy_ptr`.

Comment: Ah. I do have `==` and `!=` for the allocator type (not pictured). As for the Yoda-style `==` `!=` `+`, I deliberately left them out of my repo on the YAGNI principle. (I agree they are required by the Standard, though.)