# How do you check that a class/template implements a set of traits?

Tags: c++, type-traits

If I create a custom template or class that is supposed to implement a concept defined by a set of traits. How can I test that it actually does implement that concept?

Is there a generally accepted way of doing this for 'traits' classes?
([concepts in C++20](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) are the accepted way in
general but I am currently limited to C++14-ish)

Or is it just a case of having to remember?

Some related examples:

- If I write a fancy pointer that I want to be sure implements [pointer_traits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/pointer_traits). How can I check that it actually does?
- If I write a custom allocator that I want to be sure implements [allocator_traits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits). How can I check that it actually does?
- How can I check I've properly implemented [iterator_traits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits)?

For example if I implement a ['fancy' pointer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator#Fancy_pointers) along the lines of [boost::interprocess::offset_ptr](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/doc/html/interprocess/offset_ptr.html):

I do the normal things:

- implement & test constructors    from T* T&
- implement & test comparisons     <=, <, !=, ==, >=, >=
- implement & test dereferencing    operator* & operator->
- implement & test assignment
- implement & test pointer arithmetic   ++, --, -, +, +=, -=

To use this type with an allocator we need to implement pointer traits.
Is it just a case of implementing to_address() and pointer_to()?

You can make a pointer-like class which does not implement comparisons or pointer arithmetic.
Would that still be a valid model of pointer_traits?
This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45132546/should-every-fancy-pointer-be-an-iterator) suggests that a valid pointer must implement the random access iterator concept.
So the answer would seem to be no.
That question is also close to what I'm trying to do.

I expect there are two answers to this.
A concepts version and one for earlier iterations of C++. I am interested in both though I am currently limited to C++14.

There is the obvious answer which is to add a test which uses the thing you want to use.
So we add an allocator which uses the pointer and add a test using that allocator with an STL type.
This is useful and necessary but not necessarily complete or sufficient. It is also relatively speaking an integration test (does X work with Y) rather than a unit test (does X do what X should do).

It is very easy to miss something.
For example when implementing smart pointer comparisons it is easy to forget to make the following valid.

```
nullptr == smartPtr
```

Likewise I suspect there are some things that will work if some of the traits are implemented and others that won't if some a not implemented correctly.
Hence, I want to add a test or tests to the pointer class's testsuite to ensure it implements everything it needs to implemented to be used with the allocator template.

I also want to better understand what allocator traits, pointer traits and iterator traits are really doing.

Related reading:

- http://blog.nuggetwheat.org/index.php/2015/09/01/why-pointer_traits-was-introduced-in-c11/ and links.
- https://github.com/Quuxplusone/from-scratch/blob/master/include/scratch/bits/traits-classes/pointer-traits.md

---

Update 1

Speaking of missing things.
I already realised I need:

- explicit operator bool () const;
- bool operator! () const;
- rebind
- using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;

Found by attempting to instantiate boost::containers::vector and std::vector.
There are some others I am still trying to sort out along with the rebind part.