# How can I correctly add a new defaulted parameter to a template for an Allocator

Tags: c++, templates

I have two templates

```
template< template <class T> class ALLOCATOR = std::allocator >
class Foobar final
{
public:
   struct Entry
   {
      int foo;
      int bar;
   };
   using Allocator = ALLOCATOR<Entry>;
   using Container = std::vector< Entry, Allocator >;
   Container contents;
};

namespace Snafu
{

template <class T >
class Allocator
{
   using pointer = T*;
};

}
```

Later on in some test code this is instantiated as:

Allocator<Foobar::Entry> allocator(counter);

I wish to add another parameter to the second template thus:

```
template <class T, class Ptr = T* >
class Allocator
{
   using pointer = Ptr;
};
```

But this results in the following cryptic error for the previous instantiation:

```
FooTest.cpp:79:35: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for template<template<class T> class ALLOCATOR> class Foobar
    Allocator<Foobar<Allocator>::Entry> allocator(counter);
                                   ^
FooTest.cpp:79:35: note:   expected a template of type template<class T> class ALLOCATOR, got template<class T, class PTR> class Snafu::Allocator
FooTest.cpp:79:43: error: template argument 1 is invalid
    Allocator<Foobar<Allocator>::Entry> allocator(counter);
                                           ^
FooTest.cpp:79:43: error: template argument 2 is invalid
FooTest.cpp:79:62: error: cannot convert Snafu::SnafuCountingAllocator to int in initialization
    Allocator<Foobar<Allocator>::Entry> allocator(counter);
                                                              ^
FooTest.cpp:80:25: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for template<template<class T> class ALLOCATOR> class Foobar
```

If we take the analogy of a function. If I add a new parameter with a default value. I can still invoke it exactly as before.
Why does this not apply for *this* C++ template?

The obvious culprit is the 'self' referential type:

```
Allocator<Foobar<Allocator>::Entry> allocator(counter);
```

Somehow for the first case Allocator can be deduced but simply adding a default parameter breaks this.

Why?
I think it may be more proper to invert the question.
How did this work before I added the parameter?

What is the fix?

I have a suspicion it relates to my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72348662/how-do-you-check-that-a-class-template-implements-a-set-of-traits)
and [Re: Ext pointer vs N2913](https://gcc.gnu.org/legacy-ml/libstdc++/2009-10/msg00074.html).
Perhaps I need to implement some kind of 'rebind' thingamy.

---

As pointed out in the comments the problem is
there is one temlate parameter here:

```
template <class T> class ALLOCATOR
```

I have broken things by adding a new parameter to my Allocator class.
So it is no longer compatible with the template.

Also std::allocator takes exactly one template parameter.

Some template-fu is necessary to solve this.

Comment: `template <class T> class ALLOCATOR` and `template <class T, class Ptr = T* > class Allocator` have a different amount of template parameters.  You can't use the later in the former.

Comment: Your code compiles when I add the **required** semicolons at the end of each class/struct definition. OK - Maybe not, when I add the second template inside the `Snafu` namespace.

Comment: @AdrianMole Its simplified and thus pseudo-code.

Comment: Incorrect Code != Simplified Code

Comment: @NathanOliver Ah - I see the problem you spotted. I now have a bigger problem std::allocator only takes a single parameter. So I need to do something about that.

Comment: @BruceAdams Switching to `template< template <class...> class ALLOCATOR = std::allocator >` might fix it for you.