# How to store a state of custom allocator used for allocation of different types

Tags: c++, allocator

In a situation where one needs to work with custom *state*ful allocator, what is the idiomatic way to store the *state*, if the state should be used to allocate objects of different types? E.g. if one needs a *allocator-aware* object, that uses data-structures of different types, such as the following:

```cpp
struct Foo
{
    std::vector<int> ints;
    std::vector<double> doubles;
    void bar() { std::vector<std::string> strs; }
}
```

I tried two solutions:
(1)

```cpp
template<typename Alloc>
struct Foo
{
    Foo(const Alloc& alloc) : alloc(alloc), ints(alloc), doubles(alloc) {}

    Alloc alloc;
    std::vector<int, typename std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::template rebind_alloc<int>> ints;
    std::vector<double, typename std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::template rebind_alloc<double>> doubles;
    void bar() { std::vector<std::string, typename std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::template rebind_alloc<std::string>> strs(alloc); }
};

custom_allocator<char> alloc(state); // any type, will be rebound
Foo<custom_allocator<char>> foo(alloc);
```

Assuming the state of the allocator is easy to copy, than this solution is fine, but writing the rebind machinery (`typename allocator_traits::template rebind`) and the fact that I have to specify (some) type (`char`) is giving me a headache.

(2)

```cpp
template<template<typename> typename Alloc>
struct Foo
{
    struct dummy_t{};

    Foo(const Alloc<dummy_t>& alloc) : alloc(alloc), ints(alloc), doubles(alloc) {}

    Alloc<dummy_t> alloc;
    std::vector<int, Alloc<int>> ints;
    std::vector<double, Alloc<double>> doubles;
    void bar() { std::vector<std::string, Alloc<std::string>> strs(alloc); }
};

custom_allocator<char> alloc(state); // any type, will be rebound, or
custom_allocator alloc2(state); // if I make <T = char> in my allocator implementation
Foo<custom_allocator> foo(alloc);
```

Which seems better with the declaration noise, but is somehow different to how STL looks (as that accepts a specific allocator, whereas (2) accepts an allocator template).

Ideally I would want a single allocator (i.e. non-template) with templated `construct`, as that wouldn't require any rebinding/conversions, but that's sadly not what the STL containers accept.

Am I missing something obvious, or are these ((1) or (2)) the *reasonable* ways?

EDIT:
In my proposals the state of the allocator is actually not shared between the vectors, but rather copied, but I am fine with that, as in my problem, the state is immutable.

Comment: @DanielLangr sorry, missed that out, added initialization of members in ctor, which uses the specific allocator

Comment: @Zereges But the member variable `Foo::alloc` is still not used. You are passing the constructor parameter `alloc` as an argument to vector's initialization.

Comment: Do you want both vectors to share the same allocator state? If so, see [How can I pass the exact same state of an custom allocator to multiple containers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43233949/580083)

Comment: @DanielLangr True, I actually need `Foo` to always use the allocator, e.g. not only in members, but also internally in methods. I want both vectors to share the same allocator state, but I would also like to have multiple `Foo` instances each having a different state (in my solution the vectors do not share the state, but I am fine with that as I can make the state immutable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use pmr.

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory_resource>

struct foo {
    std::pmr::memory_resource& mem {*std::pmr::get_default_resource()};
    std::pmr::vector<int> vi{&mem};
    std::pmr::vector<double> vd{&mem};
};
```

Comment: So, writing a custom `memory_resource` instead of an allocator?

Comment: @Zereges You can also use an pmr allocator and other pmr container can be constructed by the pmr allocator. Nothing different. However, I'm not sure what the template parameter for the pmr allocator, so I use `memory_resource`.